# QTest dosnt compile

Tags: c++, qt, qtestlib

```
    /usr/include/qt5/QtTest/qtestmouse.h:161: undefined reference to `QTest::defaultMouseDelay()'
    /usr/include/qt5/QtTest/qtestmouse.h:206: undefined reference to `QTest::qWarn(char const*, char const*, int)'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Im create simple test:

```
#include <QtTest/QTest>

#include "TestHuff.h"
#include "HuffmanCode.h"

void TestHuff::SimpleTest()
{}
```

If I remove `#include <QtTest/QTest>` it compiles well.

Comment: Do you have QT += testlib in your pro file?

Comment: No. Thank you. Sorry for my mistake. I forgot about that.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld you should change your comment to an answer

Comment: I had `CONFIG += testlib` _**sigh**_